# Is there a process/practice for replacing a JSON value? Specifically, replacing an API URL with a value provided by the API

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I'm using the Star Wars API to practice, but I am running into a weird bug. I'm pretty sure I am the problem here but I don't know enough about these processes to find the issue.

**I am creating profile cards with this info, but when I try to replace the homeworld url with the actual name, I am unable to change the value that appears in my react element.**

This is a smaller version of the JSON object that I get from the API.

```
{
  "name": "Luke Skywalker",
  "height": "172",
  "mass": "77",
  "birth_year": "19BBY",
  "gender": "male",
  "homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",           
},
```

I was trying to replace the url value of homeworld with the name of the actual homeworld before saving it to my `this.state` array. I've tried making the fetch calls from the element files (that didn't really feel proper). So I hacked some code together and watched it change with `console.log();`. It's not the prettiest.

```js
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(array => {
        console.log(array.results);

        Promise.all(array.results.map(character => {
          console.log(character.homeworld)

          let home_url = character.homeworld;
          fetch(home_url)
            .then(home => {return home.json()})
            .then(home_json => character.homeworld = home_json.name)
        }))
        .then(() => {
          console.log(array.results)
          this.setState({characters:array.results})
        });
      });
```

The `console.log();` shows that the value for homeworld was changed to the string `'Tatooine'`. This is the same all the way down to the profile card. So I was expecting this to be the value in the card to be `'Tatooine'`, but I end up with `"https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"`.

At this point I don't know where my lack of knowledge is. I'm not sure if it is an issue with JSON, React, Fetch/Promises. So if anyone is able to offer some insight on this issue that would be great. I can add more code to the post if needed. Cheers!

Comment: possibly you just need a `return` in the second `.then` call? And in the .map

Comment: You need to `return fetch` in the second `.then` call - right now your `Promise.all` is just getting an array of `undefined`

Comment: Thanks Matthew! The return call made this work. I can see why the value wasn't updated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to return something in each `.then` call in order to keep passing updated data along. Also in `Promise.all( array.results.map(` you should return each element so that you don't end up with an array full of `undefined`.

Here is an example of how you can do this (note I'd recommend using `async`/`await` for at least the `Promise.all` section):

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(array => {
    console.log(array.results);

    return Promise.all(array.results.map(async character => {
      console.log(character.homeworld);

      const homeUrl = character.homeworld;
      const home = await fetch(homeUrl);
      const homeJson = await home.json();
      return {
        ...character,
        homeworld: homeJson,
      }
    }));
  })
  .then(characters => {
    console.log(characters);
    this.setState({ characters });
  })
}
```

Again using `async`/`await` everywhere:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

async fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://swapi.co/api/people/");
  const array = await response.json();
  console.log(array.results);

  const characters = await Promise.all(array.results.map(async character => {
    console.log(character.homeworld);

    const homeUrl = character.homeworld;
    const home = await fetch(homeUrl);
    const homeJson = await home.json();
    return {
      ...character,
      homeworld: homeJson,
    }
  }));

  console.log(characters);
  this.setState({ characters });
}
```

Then `this.state.characters` is an array of length 10. Here is a sample element:

```
{
    birth_year: "41.9BBY"
    created: "2014-12-10T15:18:20.704000Z"
    edited: "2014-12-20T21:17:50.313000Z"
    eye_color: "yellow"
    films: (4) ["https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/"]
    gender: "male"
    hair_color: "none"
    height: "202"
    homeworld: {name: "Tatooine", rotation_period: "23", orbital_period: "304", diameter: "10465", climate: "arid", …}
    mass: "136"
    name: "Darth Vader"
    skin_color: "white"
    species: ["https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"]
    starships: ["https://swapi.co/api/starships/13/"]
    url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/4/"
    vehicles: []
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with an async function. This was the other flow that I tried, my understanding of async/await functions is also pretty new. I'll try to implement this and get back to you with any questions that come up.

Comment: @Jordan sure, let me know how it goes

Comment: Hey Henry, It looks like the async function is still running and hasn't changed any data by the time `render()` is called. I end up running into errors and the console logs in a different order. Is this how a promise would differ from an async function? An async is truly asynchronous! And we wait on promises?

Comment: @Jordan this is a common issue when making an API request (or any async action) in a `componentDidMount` method. The `render` method is called pretty much immediately after the constructor is called, so your `render` method should be able to handle the case when `componentDidMount` has not finished yet. This is where/why it's important to set an initial state of the correct type (e.g. `characters: []`), you can also add an `isLoading` state variable and then just render a loading component if `isLoading` is true.

Comment: You definitely answered the question in the first sentence. `You need to return something in each .then call in order to keep passing updated data along.` Thanks @Henry.